# Microsoft.FSharp.Collections vs System.Collections.Immutable

Tags: .net, collections, f#, immutability

I recentry found out that there's a bunch of [immutable collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .Net

F# is a language with focus on immutability and it has its own [immutable data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee353413.aspx). Interestingly, I saw no reference to abovementioned immutable collections in any reading on F#.

I am wondering is there any relationship between those immutable collections and F# collections? Is there any guideline what to use? What is better, F# `Map<_,_>` or `ImmutableDictionary(TKey, TValue)` and so on?

**UPDATE** Maybe I could ask it as follows: does anybody have any experience using both these libraries in same project or have compared their productivity? Or it's just like that - first are for C# and latter are for F# and that's it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'better'? Better how? F# collections are built-in and were made with F# in mind, that's why they will be more idiomatic in use. Immutable collections are rather targeted at C#, which is (was) severely lacking in that department...

Comment: Basically in my opinion if you need to share this collection with C# / VB.NET code that possibly will make sense avoid F# specific data types (note that it still being possible to pass F# data type by adding F# Core dll to both projects). Other way it will be better to work with language specific types.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek I mean better in any sense: speed, memory, ease of use, for example. It just seems strange to me that there are two similar things and I want to undestand if I have missed some interesting difference between them

Comment: @Rustam in F# it's easier (not sure about speed and memory) to use F# collections, they are designed for it.

Comment: @Heather well yes, I guess so. Static methods in these classes make their use more "functional"

Comment: The author of System.Collections.Immutable claims [performance comparable to mutable data types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2011/08/29/immutable-collections-with-mutable-performance/). If this is true, then it's unequivocally better than the F# libraries, as far as performance is concerned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this duplication is simply that `System.Collections.Immutable` is a recent addition and is intended for use in C#, so its designers understandably didn't want people to have to reference `FSharp.Core.dll`.

As for choosing between the two, I would use `System.Collections.Immutable` in C# code and in F# code that is intended to be used from C#, and `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections` in all other F# code. AFAIK there is no significant difference in terms of performance. Typical code will look like chained method calls with S.C.I and series of `|>` calls with M.F.C but this is just a syntactic difference really -- conceptually it's the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add my 2 cents: my current research gives an impression that `System.Collections.Immutable` is something that should help to program F# while you program C# ))

Here's MSDN [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/09/25/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time.aspx) on them. It references [another post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2013/01/08/simple-immutable-objects.aspx) (MSDN too). And in this article there's a broken reference to T4 template which can be used to create immutable objects easily in C#: here's a [TT file](https://github.com/AArnott/ImmutableObjectGraph/blob/master/Demo/Message.tt) and here's a [scary result](https://github.com/AArnott/ImmutableObjectGraph/blob/master/Demo/Message.generated.cs) of transformation.

This is clearly a great work, but is seems to reproduce (by using `System.Collections.Immutable`) features that already and naturally exist in F#.

Hence the answer currently seems to be - `System.Collections.Immutable`are for C# and `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections` are for F# and that's it.